# How can I insert a multiptes value onclicked inside my submit function

Tags: javascript, css

*I'm creating a simple app with the name of tip calculator, I have multiples buttons, the idea is the user should type the amount of the bill then click on one of the buttons to select the value of the tip then type the number of the persons and then submit to get Tip amount/Person and the Total/person.
I got stuck in the part of not knowing how to insert the value of buttons in my formula? What do you think?*

```js
const submitEl = document.getElementById("submit-btn");
const form = document.getElementById("form");



const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const billEL = document.getElementById("bill").value; 
    const peopleNum = document.getElementById("peopleNum").value;
    const tipAmount = document.getElementById("tip-amount");
    const totalEl = document.getElementById("total");
    const inputTip = document.getElementById("tip-input").value;
    const tipButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".tip-btn");
    console.log(tipButtons)

    // To calculate the bill per person
    let billPerPerson = (billEL / peopleNum).toFixed(2);
    
    // To calculate the tip for per person
    let tipPerPeron= ((inputTip / 100) * billPerPerson);

    tipAmount.innerHTML=`<span>$</span>${tipPerPeron}`;
    totalEl.innerHTML=`<span>$</span>${billPerPerson}`;

    Array.from(tipButtons).forEach((btn)=> {
        btn.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
            const value = e.target.value;
            
        })
    })
    

}

//Event Listener
form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tip Calculator Tip</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1 class="title">Splitter</h1>
            <form class="container" id="form">
                <div class="left-side">
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="bill">Bill</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" id="bill">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="tip">Select Tip $</label>
                        <div class="selected-tip">
                            <button type="button" class="tip-btn" value="5">5%</button>
                            <button type="button" class="tip-btn" value="10">10%</button>
                            <button type="button" class="tip-btn" value="15">15%</button>
                            <button type="button" class="tip-btn" value="25">25%</button>
                            <button type="button" class="tip-btn" value="50">50%</button>
                            <input  type="text" id="tip-input"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-control">
                        <div class="labels">
                            <label for="numPeople">Number of people</label>
                            <label for="Error" id="error">Can't be zero</label>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" id="peopleNum">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="right-form">
                <div class="form-controls">
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <div class="tip-amount">
                            <h2>Tip Amount</h2>
                            <span>/ Person</span>
                        </div>
                        <h1 id="tip-amount">$0.00</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-control total">
                        <div class="total">
                            <h2>Total</h2>
                            <span>/ Person</span>
                        </div>
                        <h1 id="total">$0.00</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <button class="reset-btn" id="submit-btn">Reset</button>
                </div>  
            </form>
        </main>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the default behavior of a `<button>` is to submit the form so adding a `type="button"` attribute to it would stop it from submitting.

Next thing you want in an `eventHandler` on the `buttons` to detect clicks,
the simplest way for me is to add a `class="tip-btn"` to the `buttons`,
then select then in javascript like so:

```
const tipBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.tip-btn')
```

After this `tipBtns` would be a collection so we iterate it and add an `eventListener`

```
Array.from(tipBtns).forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        // do code
    })
})
```

then inside `eventListener` we add some code to get the value of the clicked button

```
const value = e.target.value
```

where `e` is the `event`, `target` is the `html button`, and `value` is the `attribute`.

Then code to select the input we want changed

```
const input = document.querySelector('#tip-input')
```

and just change the value of the input and this would be our button click event listener

```
Array.from(tipBtns).forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        const value = e.target.value
        const input = document.querySelector("#tip-input")
        input.value = value
    })
})
```

Edit: Also as stated by @IsharaM the `const inputTip` that selected that value is placed outside of the `submitHandler` it should be inside of it.

Comment: I've tried your method, I really like it but it not working because first I don't get the value of the button until I submit it, so the value is not inserted inside the formula to show the result, and assuming that I will get the value of the button on click but how I can insert it inside the formula who is located in the global scope? thank you (I edited the code)

Comment: Sorry for the wait, if you want to submit the `.tip-btn` is pressed you can do that by adding `document.querySelector('form').submit()` at the end of the `btn eventListener`

Answer (score 0):

One reason for not getting the tip amount, even when typed on the text field(tip-input) is, you have defined the `inputTip` outside the `submitHandler` function as a const.
In order to dynamically get the value whenever `Reset` is clicked,

`const inputTip = document.getElementById("tip-input").value;` should be defined inside the `submitHandler` function.